# CakePHP submit form then redirect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cakephp, redirect

I'm trying to create a button that submits a form then redirects to another page.

```
$('#saveApp').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("form[id='CustomerSaveForm']").submit(); // use the native submit method of the form element
        window.location.href = "<?php echo EWConfig::$URL?>/ExpressWay/ProgramApplications/sales/residence";

        return true;
    });
```

This will redirect but not submit the form although commenting out the `event.preventDefault()` will do the opposite.

Comment: any reason to not redirect from server side?

Comment: Its only redirecting on this button click. Another button submits the form and does not redirect. So I didn't think server-side was the best option.

Comment: you could use `ajax` post then `$.post(...)` using `done` event to make sure when to redirect (helps to sort validations etc also), more info here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: We did end up going with a server-side solution. thanks for the help!

Comment: window.location.href = "<?php echo EWConfig::$URL?>/ExpressWay/ProgramApplications/sales/residence";  should have been = <?=EWConfig::$URL;?> + "/ExpressWay/ProgramApplications/sales/residence"; I think.  There's also a possibility the php block has to be wrapped in quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a server-side solution.

**View**

```
echo $this->Form->button('Save and Redirect', array('name' => 'data[redirect]'));
```

**Controller**

```
if(!is_null($this->request->data('redirect'))){
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Program', 'action' => 'index'));
}
```